# Help with Java code for sorting GPA

Tags: sorting, java

I'm tutoring a high school student and she has a CS assignment that I don't know how to help her with.

She is supposed to "write a method that will take an array of students and return the student with the highest GPA."

The code given states

```
public class Student {
   private String myName;
   private double my GPA;

   public Student (String n, double gpa) {
      myName = n;
      myGPA = gpa;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return myName;
   }

   public double getGPA() {
      return myGPA;
   }

   /* other methods not shown */
}
```

We know what they are asking, but we don't know exactly how to do it. We say they are asking us to sort people and their GPA, and then return JUST the student who has the highest GPA. Should we sort first, and then extract? Is there anything else going on?

Comment: There is for that matter no reason to sort the array. Just go through the whole array and keep track of which student was found to have the highest GPA.

Comment: Other than implementing a comparable, simply loop through the entire arraylist and get the max GPA. Based on the index of the arraylist, return the arraylist emelent. You are tutoring a student, but why are you not able to do this kind of question? Just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is by making Student implement Comparable:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
...
    int compareTo(Student s){
         return Double.valueOf(myGPA).compareTo(s.getGPA())
    }
...
}
```

And then use:

```
Collections.sort(studentlist);
studentlist.get(0);
```

**EDIT:** Adjusted the code to work with primitive doubles, thanks to  @ThanksForAllTheFish comment

Comment: This would be the simplest and most elegant way. If you cannot modify the student class (unable make it implement Comparable), you're stuck with implementig a sorting algorithm yourself. Google Bubblesort or Gnomesort.

Comment: @mish not needed. `Collections.sort` has a second signature which takes a `java.util.Comparator`. If modifying the class `Student` is not allowed, the OP can create a comparator

Comment: @Xipo in OP question GPA is a primitive, so your code is broken (though in theory right). `Double.valueOf(myGPA).compareTo(s.getGPA())` fixes your code

Comment: @ThanksForAllTheFish haven't thought about that. Thanks for the input.